# Specifying thread pool size in executor doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I have a spring boot project. I am trying to call some method asynchronously. I followed this documentation: https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/. In `Application.java`, I have added following method:

```
    @Bean
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Rules-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
```

Please note that I have set pool size to 2. But when I call the async method 5 times, five different threads get created with different ThreadNamePrefix.

```
2017-12-01 19:16:00.901  INFO 32000 --- [cTaskExecutor-5] hello world
2017-12-01 19:16:00.930  INFO 32000 --- [cTaskExecutor-4] hello world
2017-12-01 19:16:01.372  INFO 32000 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] hello world
2017-12-01 19:16:01.376  INFO 32000 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] hello world
2017-12-01 19:16:01.985  INFO 32000 --- [cTaskExecutor-3] hello world
```

I am not sure from where it's getting configured. Can someone please help?

**Update:**

Here is the code from where I am submitting the tasks:

```
@Component
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    private Async2 async;

    public void someMethod()
    {
        try {
            async.anotherMethod(1);
            async.anotherMethod(2);
            async.anotherMethod(3);
            async.anotherMethod(4);
            async.anotherMethod(5);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Service
public class Async2 {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Async2.class);
    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<Void> anotherMethod(int i) {
        LOGGER.info("hello world");
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    }
}
```

**Update2**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/a")
public class WebController {
    @Autowired
    private MyClass c;

    @RequestMapping(value="/b", method =RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody Response getResponseForRequest(@RequestBody Request request)
    {
        c.someMethod();
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the part where you are submitting tasks?

Comment: @VDanyliuk I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Please tell me where you call your `someMethod()`? This method is call at the initialization stage of the spring context (from method with `@PostConstruct` annotation e.g.)? Looks like spring did not have time to initialize your `Executor`

Comment: @eshtio I am calling the method from a web service endpoint. And I call the service once the initialization is completed(i.e. application has started successfully). Please have a look at the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution. First of all, I had to specify the name of the bean and use the bean-name in Async2 class.

```
@Bean(name="rulesThreadExecutor")
public Executor asyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Rules-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}

@Async("rulesThreadExecutor")
public CompletableFuture<Void> anotherMethod(int i) {
    LOGGER.info("hello world");
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
}
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your first version, but i can't do it. My code with your logic works correctly (all threads have custom prefix). Do you identify what was a problem? Please tell me if yes or share your first version please and i'll try to understand your problem

Comment: @eshtio I created a new project and did all things that were there in my first version, and it was working perfectly fine. The problem was with an existing project, I tried to modify that and I was not getting the expected result. Finally, I had to try the second version and it worked. I couldn't find out the exact problem in existing project.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you configuration class with custom `asyncExecutor` wasn't loaded. Check that it is scanned by Spring and `@EnableAsync` annotation is present. Also in your sample `anotherMethod` doesn't return `CompletableFuture`.

Here is minimal working sample :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@RestController
public class AsyncApp {

    @Bean
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Rules-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Service
    public class AsyncService {
        @Async
        public CompletableFuture<Void> async() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
            System.out.println("Hello from " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private AsyncService asyncService;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public void test() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            asyncService.async();
        }
        System.out.println("Return from Controller");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AsyncApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

The output is :

```
Return from Controller
Hello from Rules-2
Hello from Rules-1
Hello from Rules-2
Hello from Rules-1
Hello from Rules-2
```